# Python convert Counter object into list of ordinals

Tags: python, list, counter

I think this should have a relatively simple solution.

I have a Counter object and, from it, I want to make a list composed of integers that represent the ordinal values of each key in the Counter object.

Illustration of what I mean:

Let's say this is my counter object -

```
Counter(elems)

Counter({'elem1': 13,
         'elem2': 13})
```

From this, I want to generate the following type of "ordinal" list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

I've tried a few things, such as this:

```
ord_list = [i for i in range(1, v + 1) for k, v in Counter(elems).items()]
```

But the closest I keep getting is `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4..., 13, 13]` rather than what I'm looking for.

What blindingly obvious thing am I missing? Thanks everyone.

Comment: i'm not sure I understand what you want? Would `[i for i in range(max(Counter(sesh_subj).values())+1)]` do? how does the ordinal list relate to `Counter`?

Comment: Sorry, firstly, the 'sesh_subj' part is a copy and paste error which I've edited to make things clearer. I can't use 'max' since, although it's the case in the illustration I gave, the elements in the Counter object won't always have the same count value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the second loop that will add each individual number from every range to the outer list. Also, keep in mind it is not needed to iterate over `items` because you don't use the keys anywhere so just iterate over `values`.

```
d = {'elem1': 13,
     'elem2': 13}

print([num for v in d.values() for num in range(1, v + 1)])
```

Or you can use `itertools.chain` to flatten the sublists for, in my opinion, a longer solution but more readable/descriptive:

```
from itertools import chain

d = {'elem1': 13,
     'elem2': 13}

print(list(chain.from_iterable(range(1, v + 1) for v in d.values())))
```

Comment: Thanks for these two solutions. I'm not overly familiar with itertools, but I guess this could be the trigger for me to change that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need:

```
elems = {'elem1': 13, 'elem2': 13}
ord_list = [i for k, v in Counter(elems).items() for i in range(1, v + 1)]
print(ord_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Comment: It's pointless to iterate over `items` since you don't need `k`. Just iterate over `values`

Comment: I just tried to fix his code instead of providing a new solution so that he can easily follow what he is doing. He can even change `.items()` to `.values()` instead to get only values.

Comment: That's exactly what I suggested, not sure I understand the "he can even" part in your comment...

Comment: What I meant is that it should be easier for him to follow and understand what he has first then later he can **optimize** his code by changing `.items()` to `.values()` or even come up with a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I edited 'sesh_subj' to 'elems' in my original post now, maybe you can too.

Comment: OK. I have updated the variable name to `elems` ;)